# How can I force apps to open on the monitor that the icon is on?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I recently set up a 2-monitor set up. When I game, I have a couch and a TV. Across the room there is a little monitor with a more work like with it's own mouse and keyboard for, well, work. Since I can't see the TV when using the work monitor, I would like to make it so that if a program is started from the TV's desktop, (which is the primary display), it opens on the TV and if I open something on the small work monitor it opens on the work monitor as opposed to the primary TV where everything opens now by default.

How can I do that?

Comment: What is happening now?

Comment: If I open a program on the secondary monitor, the window will open on the primary monitor, which is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to obtain third party programs.

I recommend Display Fusion.

Comment: I started the 30 day trial of it and I see how to force certain apps to open on certain sides but not how to make apps open on whatever side the icon was clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

[www.ultramon.com](http://www.ultramon.com) - best $40 i ever spent.

Right click on the icon, properties and you can do all sorts of fancy things, including turning on and of monitors when you start/exit programs. Good for gaming.

Comment: Ultramon provides exactly the functionality you are describing. Shortcuts (Icons) can be customized to launch their applications on a specific monitor.